# Cannot find i2c-dev.c in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers

I'm a new learner in Linux drivers.

Why I can not find the file `i2c-dev.c` on my Ubuntu 18.04?
When I use command to search

```
~# find / -iname i2c-dev.c
```

it shows nothing.

But when I check the major numbers of devices by using command

```
~# cat /proc/devices
```

it shows me that i2c has a major number of 89.

So there must be a `i2c-dev.c` file in my ubuntu 18.04 to add my i2c device to the kernel, but why I can not find it?

Comment: You can find the source codes at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/i2c

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that for proper functioning of a Linux kernel module, it is not necessary that the _source code_ file is present on the system; it is sufficient to have the compiled binary file present. In most Linux distributions, all software packages (including the kernel) are _a priori_ distributed only in binary form, because shipping the source code along by default would only clutter up disk space. For those parts where the license allows it, there are usually tools to retrieve the source code easily, though; often these tools are even installed by default.